# using MySql.data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

i am connect to a mysql database using this example:

http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html

at the top the instruction is to:

Next add reference to: MySql.Data

how do i do that?

Comment: That means adding it to the list of DLLs the compiler and thus your resulting code use.  Are you using a IDE?  If so, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click your project, click Add Reference, and browse to MySql.Data.dll.